# Is it possible to only offset bootstrap columns on large devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column composed of a title that I offset-ed in order to make it float on the right side of the page. Is it possible to only implement this on medium devices and up? I want it to be able to be centered on small devices (such as phones) only. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="section header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="offset-md-4 name">
      <h1>temple naylor</h1>
      <h5>Full Stack Web Developer</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't using an actual Bootstrap class: it should be `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 name">`. See [grid offsetting](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Comment: When doing so it makes the <h1> tag stack like so: http://imgur.com/a/uboq4 any way to fix this? Please post a answer so I can mark you as correct. @vanburen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**yes**, it is possible only offset on large devices.

When you used `col-md-offset-4` is only effect above 992px screen size not effect in mobile device

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 name">
      <h1>temple naylor</h1>
      <h5>Full Stack Web Developer</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I must ask, why was the css border contained within your answer?

Comment: just want to show you it is possible for offsetting on large devices.

Comment: for bootstrap 4 users, the offset class name is slightly different: offset-md-4